# How can I disable OpenSSL md5 hashing on a FIPS Enabled RedHat6 Server

Tags: bash, openssl, md5

I am looking to disable md5 hashing on my FIPS Enabled Redhat6 Server.

Documentation shows that once FIPS mode is enabled on a Linux server md5 algorithmic hashing gives an error like the below output but this not the case with my server.

I checked the server and FIPS is enabled but md5 hashing still works.

Expected output in FIPS mode should be:

```
$ openssl md5 /dev/null
Error setting digest md5
140647163811744:error:060800A3:digital
```

Current output on my server:

```
$ sudo openssl md5 /dev/null
MD5(/dev/null)= d41d8cd98f00b204e980099

$ sudo sysctl –a | grep fips

crypto.fips_enabled = 1
```

Anyone with experience to fix this?